# Dividing an integer by a number with a fraction

Tags: education

There is a way regular people use to multiply a number with a number with a fraction. For example, multiply 6*2.5. They multiply 6*2=12 then 6*.5=3 then they add 12+3 to get the final result 15. I am trying to use the same way but with dividing not multiplying but I get a result that I was not expecting. I divided 6/2=3 then 6/.5=12 then subtracted 3 from 12 to get 9. When the actual result should be 2.4. My question is, can it be done the same way with multiplying, working with the integer then working with the fraction?

Comment: Because division is not distributive:$$a(b+c)=ab+ac\qquad\frac{a}{b+c}\ne\frac{a}b+\frac{a}c$$

Comment: Thanks Peter. Why did not you post it as an answer?! I can not vote it up or accept it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer, no.

$2.5$ means $2+.5$, so $6\times2.5 = 6\times(2+.5)$. Then, by the distributive law of multiplication over addition, it equals $6\times2+6\times.5$.

However, there is no distributive law of division over addition, so there's no way in general to rewrite $6\div2.5 = 6\div(2+.5)$ in a similar way.

Comment: I believe by now that there is no distributive law neither over addition nor subtraction.

Answer (score 0):

It cannot be done. Although $a(b+c) =ab +ac$, $\frac{a}{b+c} \ne \frac{a}{b} \pm \frac{a}{c}$ in general.